# First meeting with my PhD supervisor

Tags: phd, advisor, etiquette

In my country, the graduate school and department assign you to a supervisor based on your research and specialization. After admission, you are expected to formally meet your supervisor.

I never met my supervisor before. How should I prepare for this meeting?

Comment: Duplicate. See [ http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/51687/what-is-the-time-and-topic-etiquette-for-a-first-meeting-with-a-professor-to-dis ] and many more if you search using the term "first meeting" [ http://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=first+meeting ].

Comment: I am not sure about the duplicate, because we are lacking information as PhD programs vary strongly in nature between countries and fields. Does this happen within a graduate school? Do you already have a contract (if you need one in your setting)? How did this preson become your supervisor if you never met him? Voting to close as *unclear* for now.

Comment: Thanks. It does happen In some countries. In mine you are assigned to a supervisor based on your research and specialization. It is the responsibility of graduate school and the department to do so. After admission, you are expected to formally meet your supervisor. Hope am clear now

Answer (score 4):

My first meeting with both my PhD and MS supervisor were fairly informal. Talk about research, talk about moving to the new area, ect. Generally set up stuff. They also showed me my new office. You don't really need to prepare unless you don't know much about what your new supervisor does. Relax, there will be plenty of time to stress in graduate school: now is not the time.